# Java: Why can't I read and compare the text files?

Tags: java, netbeans

What i'm trying to do is after the user select items from combobox and click on a button, case 2 will run and the txtcp will set the text box to RK1314 and save it into the text file

```
case 2: if (sportcb.getSelectedItem().equals("Ferrari F430 Scuderia"))
          {
                ...
                 txtcp.setText("RK1314");
```

so after a button is pressed, i want to read and compare the text if it's present in the text file, message will appear.

```
        String line;
        String fileName = "test.txt";
        String link = txtcp.getText(); 
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

          while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.equals(link))
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," identical match found in the text file!");
          }
          br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {      
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"hello");
        }
```

Here is my code for writing to the text file:

```
        File data = new File("test.txt");

        try {
          String cname = name.getText();
          String sdate = startdate.getDate().toString();
          String edate = enddate.getDate().toString();

          if (data.exists() == false) {
            System.out.println("We had to make a new file.");
            data.createNewFile();
          }
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(data, true));
          out.append("Customer name: "+cname );
          out.append(System.lineSeparator());
          out.append("Contact Number: "+cn );
          out.append("Car plate: "+plate);
          out.append(System.lineSeparator());
          out.append("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
          out.append(System.lineSeparator());
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Order is Recorded!");
          out.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Order is not Recorded!");
        }
```

after the button is pressed, nothing happened.

Comment: i tried using FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f
     r);

but it still wont work

Comment: pl edit your question and add the information added in comment to your question text and delete the comment.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela basically it's nothing, i just tried a different way, but in the end the results is still the same

Comment: The problem may or may not be in the code you presented here. You mention GUI elements, but none of your code actually references them. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is *far* from complete *or* minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be looking for a line that is precisely equal to "RK1234"; i.e.

```
if (line.equals(link)) { ...
```

However, the code for writing the file outputs the data like this:

```
      out.append("Customer name: "+cname );
      out.append(System.lineSeparator());
      out.append("Contact Number: "+cn );
      out.append(System.lineSeparator());
      out.append("Car plate: "+plate);  // Updated ...
      out.append(System.lineSeparator());
      out.append("---------------------------------------" +
                 "---------------------------------------" + 
                 "---------------------------------------");
      out.append(System.lineSeparator());
```

None of the 4 lines produce by the above can *possibly* be equal to "RK1234".  Assuming that RK1234 is the "plate", then the line for that will be "Car plate: RK1234" ... which is NOT equal to "RK1234".

So when you press the button:

- It opens the file.
- It reads each line none of which matches (so no dialog for that)
- It doesn't throw an I/O exception (so no "Hello") dialog.
- It reaches the end of the file, closes it and finished.

In short, you don't *see* any dialogs.

Perhaps you should be testing if a line *contains* that string; e.g.

```
if (line.indexOf(link) >= 0) { ...
```

or

```
if (line.contains(link)) { ...
```

Comment: thanks alot for pointing out my problems, i re-edited the questions.

Comment: My answer still stands, even after your edits to the Question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question . The file contains like this right. 
Customer Name : Baby
Customer Number : 1234
Order Number : RK123.
So, when you are reading the file 
 It is reading line by line 
. So that please do not use the equals method. Use contains method. It will give you the result.

Answer (score -1):

Possible cause is your file is not getting written.

As per [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) The [PrintWriter(Writer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-) constructor Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing. So either you require to call `out.flush()` before `out.close()` or for creating PrintWriter use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-boolean-) contrustor, with which your can specify 'true' to autoFlush parameter.

Currently it is happening that your file is not getting written.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `out.close()` will try flush all data before closing.  If it can't it will throw an exception.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close--